# Spannable Grid Layout manager with fixed size of first items

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-manager, android-recyclerview

I am using [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) library. I have found **SpannableGridLayoutManager** useful for me.
 I am trying to achieve next result.
[image]

Let me explain this. I need to get exactly the same layout. First grid cell with rowspan = 2. As you can see on the screenshot.
You may ask me, why do I ask this question if you post desired result.
Here is one problem, current orientation of layout manager is vertical, also you may notice gray space under the layout. This is there are only three items in recycler view.
If you add more than three you will get something like that, depending on specified height.
[image]

What I need I need to have exactly the same result as on the first screenshot,but with the horizontal scroll.

If to change Layout Manager orientation to the horizontal you will probably get following result.

[image]

Of course you can play with row and colspans to get desired result, but it will be different on each screen dimension.

I need to get first three items of list exactly the same as on first screenshot, but with ability to scroll horizontally if there are more than three items.
They must be scaled independently to the screen orientation, dimension, as it works with VERTICAL layout manager orientation. But there shouldn't appear fourth, fifth item if there is enough space only three and exactly in such layout.

I have tried to play with colspans and rowspans, LayoutManager implementation, Layout Params (match parent, wrap content) and other. But haven't got desired result.

Please help to get such result, or at least where this can be set in the code.